# Changing 2 column values in the same table in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table where there is a column with different values like America, South Korea, Japan and so on. I would like to replace the values with America=USA, South Korea=SA, Japan= JP like these. In the same table, there is another column with values like Chittagong, Dhaka, Barisal. I would like to replace the values with Chittagong=CTG, Dhaka=Dhk, Barisal= Ba like these. I would like to use CASE in big query as single query. What would be the code structure?

Comment: why a CASE and not a JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `case`, then it would look like

```
select t.* except (col1, col2)
       (case when col1 = 'America' then 'USA'
             when col1 = 'South Korea' then 'SA'
             . . .
        end) as col1,
       (case when col2 = 'Chittagong' then 'CTG'
             when col1 = 'Dhaka' then 'Dhk'
             . . .
        end) as col2
from t;
```

Comment: It shows an error at the first bracket at select.Syntax error: Unexpected "(" at [2:7]

Comment: @AbdurRahim . . . I think 90% of the time I use `except`, I put the parentheses in the wrong place.

Comment: @Gordon...Thank you, It is working

Comment: @AbdurRahim If the answer worked you can accept it. That will help the later reader to know that this answer solved the problem in that question.